# JAVA JAXB - XJC producing methods returning List<Object> - best way to detect object type?

Tags: java, xml, list, object, jaxb

I've used xjc to convert a .xsd schema to Java. However being a fairly complex schema, the produced code is causing me a few headaches.

In some instances an element can have many children from a selection of a few different, but similar enough, complex typed elements. In the cases where this occurs, xjc has the get method returning a reference to a `List<object>`.

```
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-EMBEDDED-DOCUMENT", type = ATTRIBUTEVALUEEMBEDDEDDOCUMENT.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-EMBEDDED-FILE", type = ATTRIBUTEVALUEEMBEDDEDFILE.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-ENUMERATION", type = ATTRIBUTEVALUEENUMERATION.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-FILE-REFERENCE", type = ATTRIBUTEVALUEFILEREFERENCE.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-SIMPLE", type = ATTRIBUTEVALUESIMPLE.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-XML-DATA", type = ATTRIBUTEVALUEXMLDATA.class)
    })
    protected List<Object> attributevalues;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the attributevalues property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the attributevalues property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getATTRIBUTEVALUES().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link ATTRIBUTEVALUEEMBEDDEDDOCUMENT }
     * {@link ATTRIBUTEVALUEEMBEDDEDFILE }
     * {@link ATTRIBUTEVALUEENUMERATION }
     * {@link ATTRIBUTEVALUEFILEREFERENCE }
     * {@link ATTRIBUTEVALUESIMPLE }
     * {@link ATTRIBUTEVALUEXMLDATA }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Object> getATTRIBUTEVALUES() {
        if (attributevalues == null) {
            attributevalues = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.attributevalues;
    }
```

This makes life difficult because I'm only interested on a specific type of element from the selection it could contain.

Is there any way i can find out what element name a child has as i go through the list? I know of `instanceof` and `Object.getClass()` but I've been told there should be a better way than them in the vast majority of cases.

Is this one of the cases where i should use them, or does JAXB have a facility for detecting an element name without resorting to either of them?

Comment: Consider using the [JAXB2 Simplify Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin) to simplify the generated structures. You can get one property per element which would make your life simpler. Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin.

Comment: @lexicore haven't had a chance to look at it yet, but I'll definitely give it a go once I've got all the functionality working and am tuning the algorithm up.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, instanceof is probably you best bet.  That said, if all the elements have a common structure, you could create a common interface for them all.  there are bindings you can add to the schemas to get xjc to assign the interface to the relevant classes.  then your list should be the common interface instead of just Object.  However, if there isn't any additional attribute to distinguish the classes, then you are still left with "instanceof" to find the relevant type.

you could probably convince jaxb to tell you the element name for a given object instance (e.g. [JAXBIntrospector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBIntrospector.html)), but your code will still just be a giant switch on element name, which isn't really all that different from a giant switch on instanceof.

Comment: i didn't create the schema, so i can't really edit it. I ran the RIF/ReqIF schema through it to produce the relevant classes.

Comment: @ForceGaia - you can use separate bindings files to influence xjc's behavior without modifying the schemas directly (not that it matters all that much whether or not you modify the schema merely to influence the classes generated).